# How to check if password is correct in shell script?

Tags: bash

How to check if password is correct in shell script?

```
#!/bin/bash
read -sp "Enter a password:" PASS
wget www.example.com && sudo -S <<< $PASS shutdown -P 5
```

Answer (score 2):

You don't; you let `sudo` check that it is correct. That said, you also don't need that `read` statement; you can just provide `sudo` with a custom prompt and let `sudo` handle reading the password as it usually does.

```
wget www.example.com && sudo -p "Enter a password: " shutdown -P 5
```